# Joomla Module Positions not Updating After Defining in Layout Files

Tags: php, templates, module, joomla

After I made my own additions to the Joomla template files -- I added a module position in a cloned version of the layout file, added the position in the `templateDetails.xml` file, and checked that the template layout `.ini` file has my module position -- the module position still does not show up in the layout tab of the backend.

I first tried this in localhost using xampp and everything seems to work fine. Once I transfer the files using FileZilla to the server, the module positions that I added in the layout does not seem to work. I could still find the position in the dropdown, but it does not appear in the blocks of the layout tab. This is the layout that appeared using localhost, but the view that I see after I transferred the files was only the header (no "inner" or "banner" positions):

[image: This is the layout that appeared using localhost, but the view that I see after I transferred the files was only the header (no "inner" or "banner" positions.]

Comment: There's a separate joomla stackexchange site that is the best place to get your answer [joomla.se]

Answer (score 0):

Module positions are added the first time you install a template - you won't see any new module positions if you update the the XML manifest file of the template. However, you can still use these new positions if you just type in their name. Hopefully, Joomla in the future would have a method to flush and refresh module positions.